# Seeking for a solution to convert GeoTIFF to 3d WKT

Tags: qgis, gdal, dem, saga, well-known-text

I am trying to convert some DEM in .tif image to polygon geometries representing 3 dimensional triangles that is [Well-known text (WKT) - 3D (x, y, z)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)

I was able to use SAGA to convert my GeoTIFF image to TIN, but what really wanted is a WKT format as stated above.

How do I do this is in QGIS, SAGA, GDAL, PostGIS or any other open source solution?

Comment: If you've already done the first step (GeoTIFF -> TIN), then all you really need is TIN -> WKT, which at least some, probably all, of those packages can accomplish. Please choose one package and attempt the conversion, then if  you have a problem, edit the question with details of that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R you can do this with the *dev-version* of `quadmesh`, and the `sf` package.

```
library(raster)
## create a raster 
r <- raster(volcano)

## convert to indexed quad form, the rgl mesh3d format
qm <- quadmesh::quadmesh(r)

## split quad index into triangle index
tri <- quadmesh::triangulate_quads(qm$ib)

## convert to simple features
ps <- lapply(split(rbind(tri, tri[1, ]), rep(seq_len(ncol(tri)), each = 4)), 
       function(idx) sf::st_polygon(list(t(qm$vb[1:3, idx]))))
p_xyz <- sf::st_sf(geometry = sf::st_sfc(ps, crs = projection(r)))

p_xyz

Simple feature collection with 10614 features and 0 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XYZ
bbox:           xmin: 1.490116e-08 ymin: 1.490116e-08 xmax: 1 ymax: 1
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
First 10 features:
                         geometry
1  POLYGON Z ((1.490116e-08 1 ...
2  POLYGON Z ((0.01639344 1 99...
3  POLYGON Z ((0.01639344 1 99...
4  POLYGON Z ((0.03278689 1 10...
5  POLYGON Z ((0.03278689 1 10...
6  POLYGON Z ((0.04918033 1 10...
7  POLYGON Z ((0.04918033 1 10...
8  POLYGON Z ((0.06557377 1 10...
9  POLYGON Z ((0.06557377 1 10...
10 POLYGON Z ((0.08196721 1 10...
```

Then convert to text form with

```
sf::st_as_text(sf::st_geometry(p_xyz))
```

For `triangulate_quads` the development version is required, e.g.

```
devtools::install_github("hypertidy/quadmesh")
```

https://github.com/hypertidy/quadmesh

Comment: I don't much of R. But I will try it out.

Comment: > tri <- quadmesh::triangulate_quad(qm$ib)
I couldn't pass the line above for this.... "Error: 'triangulate_quad' is not an exported object from 'namespace:quadmesh'"

I not sure what package is causing that error? My sessionInfo() is....

Comment: R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

other attached packages:
[1] raster_2.8-4 sp_1.3-1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.19     lattice_0.20-35  codetools_0.2-15
 [4] crayon_1.3.4     dplyr_0.7.7      assertthat_0.2.0
 [7] grid_3.5.1       R6_2.3.0         magrittr_1.5    
[10] pillar_1.3.0     rlang_0.3.0.1    bindrcpp_0.2.2  
[13] tools_3.5.1      glue_1.3.0       purrr_0.2.5     
[16] compiler_3.5.1   pkgconfig_2.0.2  quadmesh_0.1.0  
[19] tidyselect_0.2.5 bindr_0.1.1      tibble_1.4.2    
>

Comment: quadmesh 0.1.0 on CRAN does not have the triangulate_quads function, the dev version is needed, installed from github as per the note above. (I know it's not great having to install dev code, but it's actually so simple it seemed worthwhile - you could just copy the source and use it direct - literally a single line https://github.com/hypertidy/quadmesh/blob/409a624d66cb5b673aa4ef263977a68764ce2b05/R/primitives.R#L24).

Comment: Ok, I have succeeded in installing the development version.... I will try it on my local data to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind mixing SAGA and QGIS operations:

SAGA steps (1, 2, 3)

1. **Grid to TIN** or **Grid to TIN (Surface Specific Points)**: convert DEM to TIN (which you have done so already).
2. **TIN to Shapes** `in (TIN | Tools)`: exports TIN to Shapefiles. Please select `<Points` option, which produces 2D Point Shapefile with an attribute `Value` (height data).
3. **Convert Vertex Type (2D/3D)** `(in Shapes | Tools)`: converts 2D Shapefile to 3D Shapefile. Please assign `Value` field above to the `Z` option.

QGIS step

4. Read and Save the Shapefile as a csv, with export geometry as WKT. This will create a 2D WKT field and Value field (separately). Then edit/concatenate these fields by a text editor.

Comment: that you for the steps. However, this lead to WKT points like these: POINT ZM (-116.9125692686 32.0029312393 17.7170677185059 0). What I wanted should be the POLYGONS (that is the TIN maybe with three sets of wkt) like: POLYGON Z ((...., ....., ....)?